# Get complete stack trace for one-line fatal php error

Tags: php, memory, stack-trace, backtrace

I got the following error message in my php error logs:

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5 bytes) in /lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 284

However, I want the complete stack trace, any idea how do I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your PHP config (`php.ini`) doesn't allow more than 1GB of memory, thats really huge for PHP scripting.

**make sure u don't procedure an endless loop.** When perform an endless loop with huge files or large database queries, it can happen that the memory gets full before the script stopped working by `max_execution_time` error.

If your provider allows, **you can extend the memory usage** by give it `ini_set("memory_limit","2G")` or more if needed (not recommended).

if u really want to debug this, use php "self-debuggers" in this case, put

```
echo "<pre>".print_r(debug_backtrace(),true)."</pre>";
exit;
```

before the error occurs, this display the full stack tree with args, methods, ...

You also can store the output of `debug_backtrace()` in a var and handle it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can see Xdebug with stack trace.

http://www.xdebug.org/